# Passar string mm/dd para datetime sem o ano

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

Eu tenho um dataframe com uma variável "data" que se distribui da seguinte forma:

| DATA | REGISTRO |
| --- | --- |
| 2009-05-01 | 2b |
| 2009-05-11 | 2b |
| 2009-05-11 | 3a |
| 2009-05-13 | 2b |
| 2009-05-22 | 3b |

Eu preciso de uma nova variável de data que demonstre apenas o mês/dia. Então eu gerei uma da seguinte forma:

```
df['DATA_MES'] = df['DATA'].dt.strftime('%m/%d')
```

O retorno é o seguinte:

| DATA | REGISTRO | DATA_MES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-05-01 | 2b | 05/01 |
| 2009-05-11 | 2b | 05/11 |
| 2009-05-11 | 3a | 05/11 |
| 2009-05-13 | 2b | 05/13 |
| 2009-05-22 | 3b | 05/22 |

Até aí tudo ok, porém a variável 'DATA_MES' vem como string e eu preciso dela tipo datetime. Ao tentar realizar a conversão com o seguinte código:

```
df['DATA_MES'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA_MES'], format = '%m/%d')
```

Ele completa automaticamente com 1900, da seguinte forma:

| DATA | REGISTRO | DATA_MES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-05-01 | 2b | 1900-05-01 |
| 2009-05-11 | 2b | 1900-05-11 |
| 2009-05-11 | 3a | 1900-05-11 |
| 2009-05-13 | 2b | 1900-05-13 |
| 2009-05-22 | 3b | 1900-05-22 |

Já tentei modificar os parâmetros e nada. Gostaria de encontrar uma forma de ter essa variável em formato de data mês/dia e tipo datetime.

Agradeço pela atenção desde já.

Comment: Se precisares apenas para output (string) então não precisas do objeto datetime, se for para fazer operações sobre a data então aconselho colocares em string apenas no final dessas operações. Porque precisas da data em datetime? Qual a operação que queres fazer? Ajudaria colcares aqui o csv também.

Answer (score 0):

Uma coluna de data em Pandas é uma Serie de dtype `datetime64`. Olhando a [documentação de Datetime na biblioteca do Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units), temos:

> Datetimes are always stored based on POSIX time (though having a
> TAI mode which allows for accounting of leap-seconds is proposed),
> with an epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00Z. This means the supported dates are
> always a symmetric interval around the epoch, called “time span” in
> the table below.

Significa que uma variável de dtype `datetime64` é sempre uma posição relativa criada a partir de `1970-01-01T00:00Z`. Também na documentação podemos ver que dá pra se criar uma variável a partir apenas do ano, como no exemplo abaixo. Acontece que por trás das cortinas se assume que estamos falando do dia 01/janeiro do ano que tiver sido passado.

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.datetime64('2005') == np.datetime64('2005-01-01')
True
```

Já o mesmo não é passivel de ser feito passando apenas um dia ou um mês, como abaixo:

```
>>> np.datetime64('05-01')
numpy.datetime64('0005-01')
```

Ao inves de termos o dia 01 de maio, temos Janeiro do ano 5. Além disso, como anteriormente, assume-se que se trata do dia 01, como vemos abaixo:

```
>>> np.datetime64('05-01') == np.datetime64('0005-01-01')
True
```

Acredito que o melhor pro seu caso seja ter o dia e mês em duas colunas separadas ou realmente trabalhar com essa informação como uma string.